# How to use Alexa in combination with Azure functions v4

Tags: .net, azure, azure-functions, .net-6.0, alexa-skills-kit

A few years ago I've created a POC for an Alexa skill. This skill used an Azure function (v2) that was written with .NET Core 2.1. The function returned an IActionResult at the time that contained a SkillResponse (Generated with the Alexa.NET package (v1.5.7)). Now I would like to deploy the POC but I noticed Azure functions < v4 are no longer supported and I can't create them anymore in Azure. To fix this issue I've updated the .NET Core 2.1 app to .NET 6. But as a result the response of the function changed from IActionResult to HttpResponseData and the Alexa skill no longer works. When I call the function from Postman the response does seem to be correct but still Alexa keeps returning errors like:

**Null SpeechletResponse |
Request identifier: The speechletResponse must not be null**

Is there any way to fix this issue?

The function looks something like this:

```
[Function("Alexa")]
public async Task<HttpResponseData> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequestData req)
response = ResponseBuilder.Tell("Some text");
response.Response.ShouldEndSession = true;
await httpResponse.WriteAsJsonAsync(response);
return httpResponse;
```

When I call this method in postman I get the correct response:

```
{
    "Version": "1.0",
    "SessionAttributes": null,
    "Response": {
        "OutputSpeech": {
            "Type": "PlainText",
            "Text": "Some text"
        },
        "Card": null,
        "Reprompt": null,
        "ShouldEndSession": true,
        "Directives": []
    }
}
```

I'm using Conveyor to expose my local app but this wasn't an issue before the .NET upgrade.

Any help would be welcome.

**Update**

Full function code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Alexa.NET;
using Alexa.NET.Request;
using Alexa.NET.Request.Type;
using Alexa.NET.Response;
using Alexa_AF.Models;
using Alexa_AF.RestClient;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;

namespace Alexa_AF
{
    public class AlexaFunction
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public AlexaFunction(ILogger<AlexaFunction> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Function("Alexa")]
        public async Task<HttpResponseData> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequestData req)
        {
            SkillResponse response = null;
            var httpResponse = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);

            var json = await req.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var skillRequest = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SkillRequest>(json);

            var verified = await Validator.VerifyRequestIsFromAlexa(skillRequest, req);

            if (!verified)
            {
                response = ResponseBuilder.Tell("Something went wrong validating the request");
                response.Response.ShouldEndSession = true;
                await httpResponse.WriteAsJsonAsync(response);
                return httpResponse;
            }

            var accessToken = skillRequest.Context.System.User.AccessToken;
            var user = await VerifyToken(accessToken);

            if (user == null)
            {
                await httpResponse.WriteAsJsonAsync(ResponseBuilder.Tell("Please link your account"));
                return httpResponse;
            }
            var session = skillRequest.Session;


            if (session.Attributes == null) session.Attributes = new Dictionary<string, object>();

            SystemExceptionRequestHandler(skillRequest);

            if (skillRequest.Request is LaunchRequest)
            {
                response = ResponseBuilder.Tell("Welcome");
                response.Response.ShouldEndSession = false;
                await httpResponse.WriteAsJsonAsync(response);
                return httpResponse;
            }


            if (skillRequest.Request is SessionEndedRequest)
            {
                response = ResponseBuilder.Tell("Good bye.");
                response.Response.ShouldEndSession = true;
                await httpResponse.WriteAsJsonAsync(response);
                return httpResponse;
            }


            if (skillRequest.Request is IntentRequest)
            {
                var request = skillRequest.Request as IntentRequest;
                var requestName = request.Intent.Name;

                var t = Type.GetType($"Alexa_AF.IntentClasses.{(requestName.Contains("AMAZON") ? requestName.Split('.')[1] : requestName)}, Alexa-AF");
                var responseMethod = t.GetMethod("Response", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
                var classInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(t, null);

                var returnObject = await (Task<SkillResponse>)responseMethod.Invoke(classInstance, new object[] { request, user, session, accessToken });
                await httpResponse.WriteAsJsonAsync(returnObject);
                return httpResponse;
            }

            return httpResponse;
        }

        private static void SystemExceptionRequestHandler(SkillRequest skillRequest)
        {
            if (skillRequest.Request.GetType() != typeof(SystemExceptionRequest)) return;

            var sysException = skillRequest.Request as SystemExceptionRequest;
            var message = sysException.Error.Message;
            var reqID = sysException.ErrorCause.requestId;
            switch (sysException.Error.Type)
            {
                case ErrorType.InvalidResponse:
                    break;
                case ErrorType.DeviceCommunicationError:
                    break;
                case ErrorType.InternalError:
                    break;
                case ErrorType.MediaErrorUnknown:
                    break;
                case ErrorType.InvalidMediaRequest:
                    break;
                case ErrorType.MediaServiceUnavailable:
                    break;
                case ErrorType.InternalServerError:
                    break;
                case ErrorType.InternalDeviceError:
                    break;
            }
        }

        private static async Task<UserModel> VerifyToken(string token)
        {
            if (token == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            var identityServerUrl = "...";

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(identityServerUrl))
            {
                throw new Exception("...");
            }

            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, $"{identityServerUrl}/...");
            requestMessage.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
            var result = await httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage);
            var resultAsString = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserModel>(resultAsString);
        }

    }
}
```

Validator

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Alexa.NET.Request;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;

namespace Alexa_AF
{
    public static class Validator
    {
        private static readonly string CertHeader = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----";
        private static readonly string CertFooter = "-----END CERTIFICATE-----";

        private static readonly HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();

        public static async Task<bool> VerifyRequestIsFromAlexa(SkillRequest requestBody, HttpRequestData httpRequest)
        {
            var validatedCertificateChains = new Dictionary<string, X509Certificate2>();

            if (requestBody?.Request?.Timestamp == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Alexa Request Invalid: Request Timestamp Missing");
            }

            var ts = requestBody.Request.Timestamp;
            var tsDiff = (DateTimeOffset.UtcNow - ts).TotalSeconds;

            if (Math.Abs(tsDiff) >= 150)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Alexa Request Invalid: Request Timestamp outside valid range");
            }

            var certUrls = httpRequest.Headers.GetValues("SignatureCertChainUrl");
            var signatures = httpRequest.Headers.GetValues("Signature");

            var certChainUrl = certUrls.FirstOrDefault();
            var signature = signatures.FirstOrDefault();

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(certChainUrl))
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(signature))
            {
                return false;
            }

            var uri = new Uri(certChainUrl);

            if (uri.Scheme.ToLower() != "https")
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (uri.Port != 443)
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (uri.Host.ToLower() != "s3.amazonaws.com")
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (!uri.AbsolutePath.StartsWith("/echo.api/"))
            {
                return false;
            }

            X509Certificate2 signingCertificate;

            if (!validatedCertificateChains.ContainsKey(uri.ToString()))
            {
                Trace.WriteLine("Validating cert URL: " + certChainUrl);

                var certList = await DownloadPemCertificatesAsync(uri.ToString());

                if (certList == null || certList.Length < 2)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                var primaryCert = certList[0];
                var data = new AsnEncodedData(primaryCert.Extensions[2].Oid, primaryCert.Extensions[2].RawData);
                var text = data.Format(true);

                if (!text.Contains("echo-api.amazon.com"))
                {
                    return false;
                }

                var chainCerts = new List<X509Certificate2>();

                for (var i = 1; i < certList.Length; i++)
                {
                    chainCerts.Add(certList[i]);
                }

                if (!ValidateCertificateChain(primaryCert, chainCerts))
                {
                    return false;
                }


                signingCertificate = primaryCert;

                lock (validatedCertificateChains)
                {
                    if (!validatedCertificateChains.ContainsKey(uri.ToString()))
                    {
                        Trace.WriteLine("Adding validated cert url: " + uri);
                        validatedCertificateChains[uri.ToString()] = primaryCert;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Trace.WriteLine("Race condition hit while adding validated cert url: " + uri);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                signingCertificate = validatedCertificateChains[uri.ToString()];
            }

            if (signingCertificate == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            var signatureBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(signature);

            var thing = signingCertificate.GetRSAPublicKey();
            return thing?.VerifyData(httpRequest.Body, signatureBytes, HashAlgorithmName.SHA1, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1) ?? false;
        }

        public static bool ValidateCertificateChain(X509Certificate2 certificate, IEnumerable<X509Certificate2> chain)
        {
            using var verifier = new X509Chain();
            verifier.ChainPolicy.ExtraStore.AddRange(chain.ToArray());
            var result = verifier.Build(certificate);
            return result;
        }

        public static X509Certificate2 ParseCertificate(string base64CertificateText)
        {
            var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64CertificateText);
            var cert = new X509Certificate2(bytes);
            return cert;
        }

        public static async Task<X509Certificate2[]> DownloadPemCertificatesAsync(string pemUri)
        {
            var pemText = await _client.GetStringAsync(pemUri);
            return string.IsNullOrEmpty(pemText) ? null : ReadPemCertificates(pemText);
        }


        public static X509Certificate2[] ReadPemCertificates(string pemString)
        {
            var lines = pemString.Split(new[] {'\r', '\n'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            var certList = new List<string>();
            StringBuilder grouper = null;
            for (var i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
            {
                var curLine = lines[i];
                if (curLine.Equals(CertHeader, StringComparison.Ordinal))
                {
                    grouper = new StringBuilder();
                }
                else if (curLine.Equals(CertFooter, StringComparison.Ordinal))
                {
                    certList.Add(grouper.ToString());
                    grouper = null;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (grouper != null) grouper.Append(curLine);
                }
            }

            var collection = new List<X509Certificate2>();

            foreach (var certText in certList)
            {
                var cert = ParseCertificate(certText);
                collection.Add(cert);
            }

            return collection.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Packages

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <RootNamespace>Alexa_AF</RootNamespace>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enabled</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Alexa.NET" Version="1.5.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" Version="2.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="TimeZoneConverter" Version="2.5.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Twilio.AspNet.Core" Version="5.33.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.0.13" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.14.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.19.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: please provide your full function code

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin I've added the full function code, although I don't see how most of the code matters. While debugging I've confirmed that the code goes into the if function for the LaunchRequest intent and a correct response is returned in postman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the issue. When I compared the results from the .NET Core 2.1 app with the updated .NET 6 app I noticed that the JSON response properties used to start with a small letter in the .NET Core app and now they were starting with a capital letter in the .NET 6 app.

When I added a JSON-serializer to the WriteAsJsonAsync method everything worked again.

```
var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
};

var serializer = new NewtonsoftJsonObjectSerializer(serializerSettings);

await httpResponse.WriteAsJsonAsync(response, serializer);
```